# Receive wav file and write it to disk on Node/Express Server

Tags: node.js, audio, express

I'm sending a audio file to my Node/Express server using the following:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: audio/wav" --data-binary @"hello.wav" http://127.0.0.1:3000/extract_indicators/audio/darksigma
```

And I'm using the following code:

```
 ...

app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'audio/wav', limit: '50mb' }));

 ...

app.post('/extract_indicators/audio/:user_id', function (req, res) {
  console.log("RECIEVED AUDIO TO EXTRACT INDICATORS: ", req.body);
  var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('sample.wav');
  req.pipe(writeStream);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

But the `sample.wav` file ends up being empty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your use of the `body-parser` middleware. This will read the entire file into memory, and as a result, the `req` stream will be exhausted (completely read). This means you cannot subsequently pipe it to a file (because all the data has already been read).

You have two options:

- Don't use `body-parser` at all, and pipe the request stream to the file (remove `app.use(bodyParser.raw(...))` and the rest of your code would work as expected);
- Leave the `body-parser` in and write `req.body` to a file:

  ```
  app.post('/extract_indicators/audio/:user_id', function (req, res) {
    fs.writeFile('sample.wav', req.body, function(err) {
      res.sendStatus(err ? 500 : 200);
    });
  });
  ```

Both have pro's and con's: not using `body-parser` means you have to check for the right content-type yourself, and limit the amount of data allowed to be uploaded (perhaps [`stream-meter`](https://github.com/brycebaril/node-stream-meter) can be useful there).

But *using* `body-parser` means that all uploaded files are completely read into memory first, which—especially for larger numbers of requests—can exhaust your server's memory.

Alternatively, you could consider allowing the files to be uploaded as `multipart/form-data`, so you could use something like [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer), which is pretty configurable.

cURL can handle this too:

```
curl -XPOST -F file@hello.wav http://127.0.0.1:3000/extract_indicators/audio/darksigma
```

Comment: Solution not working. without body-parser there is no req.body.

Comment: @dev_doctor the original question piped `req` to a writable stream _while_ using `body-parser`. My answer explains why that won't work. It doesn't state, or imply, that `req.body` will exist if you remove `body-parser`.